# How to get the nth largest values from a certain column using groupby and make calculations on another column on the same row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe dd:

```
Experiment  Position    Lap ID     Partition    Value
Expt1       2000        104 127327203   2       52.01
Expt1       2000        105 127327203   2       51.78
Expt1       2000        106 127327203   2       51.57
Expt1       2000        107 127327203   2       51.63
Expt1       2000        108 127327203   2       51.61
Expt1       2000        109 127327203   2       51.78
Expt1       2000        110 127327203   2       51.78
Expt1       2000        111 127327203   2       51.53
Expt1       2000        112 127327203   2       51.69
Expt1       2000        113 127327203   2       51.53
Expt1       2000        114 127327203   2       51.40
Expt1       2000        115 127327203   2       51.45
Expt1       2000        116 127327203   2       51.47
Expt1       2000        117 127327203   2       51.61
Expt1       2000        118 127327203   2       50.89
Expt1       2500        104 127327203   2       52.16
Expt1       2500        105 127327203   2       53.14
Expt1       2500        106 127327203   2       52.02
```

My data is several thousand lines and has many experiments so the above is just a snapshot.

I want to groupby Experiment then Position, and then Lap

```
grouped = dd.groupby(['Experiment','Position','Lap']) 
grouped.first()
```

This gives me:

[image]

I now want to just use the 10th largest values in the 'Lap' column to give me a mean and std of the 'Value' column.

If possible, I would then like to output to a new dataframe, the experiment, position and the result of the above calculations so I can then plot.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by counts by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for `>=10` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['Experiment','Position'])['Value'].transform('size').ge(10)]
```

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by multiple columns with [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['Experiment','Position','Lap', 'Value'])
        .groupby(['Experiment','Position'])
        .tail(10))
print (df1)
   Experiment  Position  Lap         ID  Partition  Value
5       Expt1      2000  109  127327203          2  51.78
6       Expt1      2000  110  127327203          2  51.78
7       Expt1      2000  111  127327203          2  51.53
8       Expt1      2000  112  127327203          2  51.69
9       Expt1      2000  113  127327203          2  51.53
10      Expt1      2000  114  127327203          2  51.40
11      Expt1      2000  115  127327203          2  51.45
12      Expt1      2000  116  127327203          2  51.47
13      Expt1      2000  117  127327203          2  51.61
14      Expt1      2000  118  127327203          2  50.89

df2 = df1.groupby(['Experiment','Position'])['Value'].agg([('avg','mean'),
                                                           ('q5', lambda x: x.quantile(.5))])
print (df2)
                        avg     q5
Experiment Position               
Expt1      2000      51.513  51.53
```

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't realise you could use tail in this way to filter out group sizes less than 10.     How would I get the 5th percentile rather than std?    Thanks again, its awesome

Comment: I've just realised that for the position value of 2500 where there are only 3 values, I don't want these to contribute to the calculation - only if there are 10 or more.

Comment: @user11305439 - Edited answer.

Comment: That's fantastic...but quite complicated to understand.  Can you suggest any reading for such examples. I haven't found anything on the web.   Thanks again

Comment: @user11305439 - Hard question, maybe help a bit [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html), especially modern pandas.